# estoy acostumbrado / me estoy acostumbrado

Tags: gramática, verbo-pronominal

I would like to ask you, in the case of reflective verb, for example "acostumbrarse", it is not correct to say

> Me estoy acostumbrado a estudiar hasta muy tarde.

The correct thing is

> Estoy acostumbrado a estudiar hasta muy tarde.

Is it because the structure "estar+ participio pasado" like the passive voice?

Why it is not necessary to add "reflective Se"?

Comment: I'll mention this, since I don't think that there is a typo, but a key to the answer of this question: It should be "me estoy acostumbra**n**do",  using the gerund, not the participle. Thus, "Me estoy acostumbrando" -> I'm getting used to vs. "estoy acosumbrado" ->I'm used to. Then, you could also say "Estoy aconstumbrandome" as a complete equivalent of "me estoy acostumbrando". I'll leave this for a proper answer, but I guess that you only use the reflexive with the gerund/progressive action because it means something like "I'm training / getting **myself** used to ..."

Comment: Just a detail: getting used to something can also be: becoming accustomed to. Also, there is no reflexive myself here in English.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are (understandably) mixing up two related structures.

*Estar acostumbrado (a)* is a regular *estar* + adjective predicate that can take an object (introduced by the preposition *a*). It means "to be used (to)". Of course *acostumbrado* is the passive participle of *acostumbrar*, but it functions as an adjective.

*Acostumbrarse (a)* is a pronominal verb, that is, a verb that takes a reflexive pronoun (and that is customarily cited with *se*) even though it's not really or strictly reflexive. It means "to get used (to)".

The difference, as you see, is of state vs. process. The state is expressed using *estar* plus an adjective, while the process is expressed by a verb (in this case a pronominal verb).

If you want to show an ongoing process of getting used to something, you use the Spanish equivalent of the English present continuous, i.e. *estar* plus the gerund of the main verb, which being pronominal will carry its reflexive pronoun with it: *estar acostumbrándose (a)* "to be getting used (to)".

So:

- *Estoy acostumbrado.* = "I'm used (to it)." (present, state)
- *Me acostumbré.* = "I got used (to it)." (preterite, past process)
- *Me estoy acostumbrando* ~ *Estoy acostumbrándome.* = "I'm getting used (to it)." (present, ongoing process)

Note how in the last sentence the reflexive pronoun can go before the auxiliary or attached to the end of the gerund.

Comment: yup, i think none of the original options are reflexive,  me acostumbre/me acostumbro/ acostumbrome/acostumbrarme/ those are reflexive

Comment: Yes,except I would say reflexive verb in English to describe the Spanish. Also, I would point out that we do have in English:to become accustomed to something as well. [fyi, I  u.v.'ed ]